# Queue Data structure app crash with front() method

Tags: c++, data-structures, queue, crash

I am implementing a queue data structure, but my app crashes. I know I am doing something wrong with Node pointer front or Front() method of queue class

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node 
{ 
    public: 
        int get() { return object; }; 
        void set(int object) { this->object = object; }; 
        Node * getNext() { return nextNode; }; 
        void setNext(Node * nextNode) { this->nextNode = nextNode; }; 
    private: 
        int object; 
        Node * nextNode; 
};

class queue{
    private:
        Node *rear;
        Node *front;
    public:
        int dequeue() 
        { 
            int x = front->get(); 
            Node* p = front; 
            front = front->getNext(); 
            delete p; 
            return x; 
        }

        void enqueue(int x) 
        { 
            Node* newNode = new Node(); 
            newNode->set(x); 
            newNode->setNext(NULL); 
            rear->setNext(newNode); 
            rear = newNode; 
        }

        int Front() 
        { 
            return front->get(); 
        } 

        int isEmpty() 
        { 
            return ( front == NULL ); 
        }
};
main()
{
    queue q;
    q.enqueue(2);
    cout<<q.Front();

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: After you finish writing code, the next thing you need to do is debug it. You can use a debugger, or you can add printing statements to trace its behavior. This is a skill every programmer needs to have. Muddle through it and gradually narrow down the problem. You'll start to get the hang of it and it will go faster next time.

Answer (score 0):

You're using uninitialized pointers on several occasions.

- Enqueue refers to rear->setNext(). If the queue is empty, rear is uninitialized, leading to crashes.
- Front returns the node *by some Node member-function* without checking for a non-null pointer. Why not simply return the *front pointer?
- None of your classes have a constructor. Your pointers aren't even NULL-pointers, they're just uninitialized. That's asking for troubles.

My advice:

- Give both classes a constructor.
- When calling ANY Node member-function, check for valid pointers.
- Use less Node member-functions; returns raw pointers when you can.

Comment: not working am I initializing the constructor wrong ?
queue::queue()
{
              rear=NULL;
              front=NULL;
              }

Comment: The lack of constructor isn't the only problem. You're still dereferencing null-pointers. Make sure every function checks for an empty queue (even dequeue!).

Comment: @Garminic I found my enque() method is not correct , can you fix it ?